# Trying to get SNMP Data from a badly documented system

Tags: snmp, mib

I'm trying to receive snmp data from a badly documented Device. I'll attach a copy of the docs I have.
It would be awesome if you could help me to get a snmpget command.

Best Regards
Niklas

Here are the credentials and the IP Adress:
IP: 192.168.62.219
Security Name: snmpadmin
Auth Protocol: MD5
Auth Password: 12345678
Privacy Protocol: DES
Privacy Password: ezcastdes

```
AM-SNMP-MIB DEFINITIONS ::= BEGIN

-- Design notes:
--
-- The design of this mib may seem unusual in parts, as it was
-- designed for ease of numerical management routines.
-- 
-- In that light, most sub-sections of this mib have four common
-- numerical oid consistencies:
--
-- (iana requeted).ID.1   : an integer index value.  In scalers, this is always
--               of value 1.  In tables it is a row index.
-- (47659).ID.2 : a name of the script, process, etc. that this row represents.
-- (47659).ID.100 : An error flag indicating if an error is present on
--               that row (a threshold value was crossed, etc).
-- (47659).ID.101 : An error string describing why the error flag is non-0.
--
-- These conventions enable managers to easy examine portions of the
-- mib by setting the ID to the sub-section they are interested in
-- monitoring, and then scanning the .100 value to check for an
-- error(s), and get a more specific error message from .101 for the
-- named check found in .2.
--
-- Row numbers between 2 and 100 are sub-section specific.
--
-- Mib sections utilizing the above conventions:
--   Tables:    procTable, execTable, diskTable, loadTable
--   Scalers:   memory, snmperrs


IMPORTS
    OBJECT-TYPE, NOTIFICATION-TYPE, MODULE-IDENTITY,
    Integer32, Opaque, enterprises, Counter32, Unsigned32
        FROM SNMPv2-SMI

    TEXTUAL-CONVENTION, DisplayString, TruthValue
    FROM SNMPv2-TC;

actionsmicro MODULE-IDENTITY
    LAST-UPDATED "201603310000Z"
    ORGANIZATION "Actions MicroEletronics Co. Ltd."
    CONTACT-INFO    
    " http://www.actions-micro.com
          postal:   Actions MicroEletronics Co. Ltd.
                    4F.-5, No.736, Jhongjheng Rd., Jhonghe Dist.,
                    New Taipei City, Taiwan 23511
          email:    darrelllao@actions-micro.com

        "
    DESCRIPTION
    "This file defines the private AM(ActionsMicro) SNMP MIB extensions."

    REVISION     "201603310000Z"
    DESCRIPTION
    "New object for number of CPUs as counted by the agent"
    REVISION     "201105140000Z"
    DESCRIPTION
    "New objects for monitoring CPU Steal, Guest and Nice values"

    REVISION     "200901190000Z"
    DESCRIPTION
    "New 64-bit objects for monitoring large disk usage"

    REVISION     "200611220000Z"
    DESCRIPTION
    "Clarify behaviour of objects in the memory & systemStats groups
         (including updated versions of malnamed mem*Text objects).
         Define suitable TCs to describe error reporting/fix behaviour."

    REVISION     "200404070000Z"
    DESCRIPTION
    "Added ssCpuRawSoftIRQ for Linux (2.6) and forgotten raw swap counters."

    REVISION     "200209050000Z"
    DESCRIPTION
    "Deprecate the non-raw objects."

    REVISION     "200109200000Z"
    DESCRIPTION
    "Group to monitor log files"

    REVISION     "200101170000Z"
    DESCRIPTION
    "Added raw CPU and IO counters."

    REVISION     "9912090000Z"
    DESCRIPTION
    "SMIv2 version converted from older MIB definitions."
    ::= { enterprises 47659 }

-- Current AM core mib table entries:
--   amNetworkMIB     OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { actionsMicro 1 } - AM-NETWORK-MIB
--   amProjectorMIB   OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { actionsMicro 2 }

-- Older mib table entries that were changed to new locations above:
--   (TBD)        OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { actionsMicro   1 }

-- Never implemented and removed from the mib:
--   (TBD)            OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { actionsMicro  5 }

--
-- Define the Float Textual Convention
--   This definition was written by David Perkins.
--

Float ::= TEXTUAL-CONVENTION
    STATUS      current
    DESCRIPTION
        "A single precision floating-point number.  The semantics
         and encoding are identical for type 'single' defined in
         IEEE Standard for Binary Floating-Point,
         ANSI/IEEE Std 754-1985.
         The value is restricted to the BER serialization of
         the following ASN.1 type:
             FLOATTYPE ::= [120] IMPLICIT FloatType
         (note: the value 120 is the sum of '30'h and '48'h)
         The BER serialization of the length for values of
         this type must use the definite length, short
         encoding form.

         For example, the BER serialization of value 123
         of type FLOATTYPE is '9f780442f60000'h.  (The tag
         is '9f78'h; the length is '04'h; and the value is
         '42f60000'h.) The BER serialization of value
         '9f780442f60000'h of data type Opaque is
         '44079f780442f60000'h. (The tag is '44'h; the length
         is '07'h; and the value is '9f780442f60000'h."
    SYNTAX Opaque (SIZE (7))

AMErrorFlag ::= TEXTUAL-CONVENTION
    STATUS      current
    DESCRIPTION
        "Represents a possible error condition"
    SYNTAX INTEGER  { noError(0),  error(1) }

AMErrorFix ::= TEXTUAL-CONVENTION
    STATUS      current
    DESCRIPTION
        "Represents a 'push-button' object, to invoke a suitable
         configured action.  Will always return 0 when read."
    SYNTAX INTEGER  { noError(0),  runFix(1) }

--
-- Process table checks
-- (TBD)

--
-- Memory usage/watch reporting.
-- Not supported on all systems!
-- See agent/mibgroup/ucd_snmp.h to see if its loaded for your architecture.
-- (TBD)

--    SYNTAX    OBJECT IDENTIFIER
--    MAX-ACCESS    read-only
--    STATUS    current
--    DESCRIPTION
--  "The registry slot of a mibmodule."
--    ::= { mrEntry  1 }



-- possibly used in the future:
--
-- ssErrorFlag OBJECT-TYPE
--     SYNTAX      AMErrorFlag
--     MAX-ACCESS  read-only
--     STATUS      current
--     DESCRIPTION
--         "Error flag."
--     ::= { systemStats 100 }
-- 
-- ssErrMessage OBJECT-TYPE
--     SYNTAX      DisplayString
--     MAX-ACCESS  read-only
--     STATUS      current
--     DESCRIPTION  
--         "Error message describing the errorflag condition."
--     ::= { systemStats 101 } 

END


AM-SETUP-MIB DEFINITIONS ::= BEGIN

IMPORTS
    MODULE-IDENTITY, OBJECT-TYPE, Integer32     FROM SNMPv2-SMI
    actionsmicro                                FROM AM-SNMP-MIB;

amSetUp MODULE-IDENTITY
    LAST-UPDATED "201607080000Z"
    ORGANIZATION "Actions MicroEletronics Co. Ltd."
    CONTACT-INFO
        " http://www.actions-micro.com
      postal:   Actions MicroEletronics Co. Ltd.
                4F.-5, No.736, Jhongjheng Rd., Jhonghe Dist.,
                New Taipei City, Taiwan 23511
      email:    darrelllao@actions-micro.com
        "
    DESCRIPTION
        "The AM-SNMP setup MIB."
    REVISION     "201603310000Z"
    DESCRIPTION
        "SMIv2 version converted from older MIB definitions."
    ::= { actionsmicro 1 }

amAirSetup  OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { amSetUp 1 }
amDeviceManagemant OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { amSetUp 2 }
amAccessControl OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { amSetUp 3 }
amNetworkSetup OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { amSetUp 4 }
amAdvancedSetup OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { amSetUp 5 }
amSystemInfo OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { amSetUp 6 }
amWifiWlan0 OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { amSystemInfo 1 }
amWifiWlan1 OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { amSystemInfo 2 }
amWifiWlan2 OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { amSystemInfo 3 }
amWifiWlan3 OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { amSystemInfo 4 } 
amMibLan OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { amSystemInfo 5 } 
amMibVersion OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { amSystemInfo 6} 
amMibCurstatus OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { amSystemInfo 7} 
AddNetwork  OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { amNetworkSetup 5} 

--
-- AirSetup
--
SoftApPassWord  OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX      OCTET STRING(SIZE(8..64))
    MAX-ACCESS  read-write
    STATUS      current
    DESCRIPTION
        "WiFi 2.4G and 5G use the same PSK password."
    ::= { amAirSetup 1 }

SoftApHideSSID OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX      OCTET STRING(SIZE(8..64))
    MAX-ACCESS  read-write
    STATUS      current
    DESCRIPTION
        "0:ssid is open,you can see it ;1:ssid is hidden"
    ::= { amAirSetup 2 }

EZAir OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX      OCTET STRING(SIZE(8..64))
    MAX-ACCESS  read-write
    STATUS      current
    DESCRIPTION
        "0:Mirror+Streaming;1:Mirror Only."
    ::= { amAirSetup 3 }

--
-- DeviceManagemant
--
Language  OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX      OCTET STRING(SIZE(0..2))
    MAX-ACCESS  read-write
    STATUS      current
    DESCRIPTION
        "0:en; 1:fr; 2:de; 3:es; 4:zh-CN; 5:zh-TW; 6:ja; 7:ko; 8:it; 
        9:ru; 10:nl; 11:pt; 12:tr; 13:ar; 14:tha; 15:fa; 16:auto"
    ::= { amDeviceManagemant 1 }

ChangeSSID  OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX      OCTET STRING(SIZE(8..15))
    MAX-ACCESS  read-write
    STATUS      current
    DESCRIPTION
        "The SSID length should be 1~20 characters."
    ::= { amDeviceManagemant 2 }

Resolution  OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX      OCTET STRING
    MAX-ACCESS  read-write
    STATUS      current
    DESCRIPTION
        "Get/set resolution;
        HDMI_TAB id:
        0:1280x720_50P; 1:1280x720_60P; 2:1920x1080_24P; 3:1920x1080_50P;
        4:1920x1080_60P; 5:3840x2160_24P; 6:3840x2160_25P; 7:3840x2160_30P;
        8:4096x2160_24P"
    ::= { amDeviceManagemant 3}

EDIDTable OBJECT-TYPE 
    SYNTAX     OCTET STRING (SIZE(0..1024))
    MAX-ACCESS  read-only
    STATUS      current
    DESCRIPTION 
        "the system resolution of EDID Table."
    ::= { amDeviceManagemant 4 } 

MaxConNum OBJECT-TYPE 
    SYNTAX     OCTET STRING (SIZE(0..3))
    MAX-ACCESS  read-write
    STATUS      current
    DESCRIPTION 
        "Maximum number of connections in the system.
        0: 4 users; 1: 8 users; 2: 16 users; 3: 32 users; 4: 64 users;"
    ::= { amDeviceManagemant 5 }
--
--  AccessControl 
--     


CastCodeControl OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX      OCTET STRING(SIZE(0..8))
    MAX-ACCESS  read-write
    STATUS      current
    DESCRIPTION
        "CastCodeControl 0:OFF;1:Random;2:Fixed,only 4 bit digits are allowed.
        set example:(1)0; (2)1; (3)2;6688;"
    ::= { amAccessControl 1 }


InternetAccessControl  OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX      OCTET STRING(SIZE(0..8))
    MAX-ACCESS  read-write
    STATUS      current
    DESCRIPTION
        "InternetAccessControl  0:All allowed;  1:Casting users allowed;  2:All 
        denied."
    ::= { amAccessControl 2 }

PassowrdHidden          OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX              OCTET STRING
    MAX-ACCESS          read-write
    STATUS              current
    DESCRIPTION
        "Get/Set the password status, 0:off 1:on."
    ::= {amAccessControl 3}

AirView                 OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX              OCTET STRING
    MAX-ACCESS          read-write
    STATUS              current
    DESCRIPTION
        "Get/Set the airview, 0:off 1:on.frame_rate:{5000,15000,30000,60000,0}, 
         example:1;5000;"
    ::= {amAccessControl 4}
--
--  NetworkSetup 
--     

RouterOrDirectOnly OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX      OCTET STRING (SIZE(0..1))
    MAX-ACCESS  read-write
    STATUS      current
    DESCRIPTION
        "0:Via Router Allowed; 1:Direct Link Only; 2:Via Router Only"
    ::= { amNetworkSetup 1 }

SoftApChannel OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX      OCTET STRING(SIZE(0..128))
    MAX-ACCESS  read-write
    STATUS      current
    DESCRIPTION
        "5G WiFiChannel.Warning!!,Configure without connect router.Channel Auto, input Auto.BandWidth:20/80.SetExample:5G;America;2;Auto;80;
        channel5g_regiontbl[]={ 
        1,South Africa,{36,40,44,48}; 
        1,Israel,{36,40,44,48}; 
        1,Turkey,{36,40,44,48};
        1,Egypt,{36,40,44,48};
        1,Tunisia,{36,40,44,48};
        1,Kuwait,{36,40,44,48};
        1,United Arab Emirates,{36,40,44,48};
        2,Russia,{36,40,44,48,149,153,157,161};
        2,Singapore,{36,40,44,48,149,153,157,161};
        1,South America,{36,40,44,48};
        1,Saudi Arabia,{36,40,44,48};
        2,America,{36,40,44,48,149,153,157,161};
        2,Australia,{36,40,44,48,149,153,157,161};
        2,Canada,{36,40,44,48,149,153,157,161};
        2,India,{36,40,44,48,149,153,157,161};
        2,Korea,{36,40,44,48,149,153,157,161};
        2,Malaysia,{36,40,44,48,149,153,157,161};
        2,Mexico,{36,40,44,48,149,153,157,161};
        2,China,{36,40,44,48,149,153,157,161};
        3,Iran,{149,153,157,161};
        3,Labanon,{149,153,157,161};
        3,Qatar,{149,153,157,161};
        2,Europe,{36,40,44,48,149,153,157,161};
        1,Japan,{36,40,44,48};
        2,Taiwan,{36,40,44,48,149,153,157,161};
        }"
    ::= { amNetworkSetup 2 }

WiFiManual OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX      OCTET STRING (SIZE(0..128))
    MAX-ACCESS  read-write
    STATUS      current
    DESCRIPTION
        "set wifi IP;Gateway;Netmask;DNS;   setexample:192.168.48.68;192.168.48.1;255.255.255.0;192.168.48.1;"
    ::= { amNetworkSetup 3 }

LanSet OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX      OCTET STRING (SIZE(0..128))
    MAX-ACCESS  read-write
    STATUS      current
    DESCRIPTION
        "set lan IP;Gateway;Netmask;DNS;    setexample:192.168.48.68;192.168.48.1;255.255.255.0;192.168.48.1;"
    ::= { amNetworkSetup 4 }    

--
--  AddNetwork  
--   
AddNetworkApply   OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX      OCTET STRING(SIZE(0..1))
    MAX-ACCESS  read-write
    STATUS      current
    DESCRIPTION
        "add network parameters format:ssid;authen;psk; 
        set example:action;WPA-PSK;12345678;"
    ::= { AddNetwork 1 }

ScanNetwork   OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX      OCTET STRING(SIZE(0..1))
    MAX-ACCESS  write-only
    STATUS      current
    DESCRIPTION
        "Do not need to enter any value ,just press SET key and it will scan 
        network."
    ::= { AddNetwork 2 }

ScanresultNetwork   OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX      OCTET STRING(SIZE(0..8192))
    MAX-ACCESS  read-only
    STATUS      current
    DESCRIPTION
        "get the scan network results.
        format:SSID;Authen;unknown;networkid;macaddr;"
    ::= { AddNetwork 3 }

ConnectNetwork   OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX      OCTET STRING(SIZE(0..128))
    MAX-ACCESS  read-write
    STATUS      current
    DESCRIPTION
        "set connect network ssid;authen;psk;mac;networkid;
        set example:action;WPA-PSK;12345678;84:1b:5e:d7:3a:83;-1;"
    ::= { AddNetwork 4 }

--
--  AdvancedSetup  
--     

OTAURL OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX      OCTET STRING (SIZE(0..128))
    MAX-ACCESS  read-write
    STATUS      current
    DESCRIPTION
        "OTA Server,such as http://www.iezvu.com"
    ::= { amAdvancedSetup 1 }   

AdminPassword OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX      OCTET STRING (SIZE(6..64))
    MAX-ACCESS  read-write
    STATUS      current
    DESCRIPTION
        "admin password,Password must be between 6 and 64 characters long.It is 
        md5 encrypted password when you GET it"
    ::= { amAdvancedSetup 2 }   

--
--  SystemInfo  
--     

Wlan0MacAddress OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX      OCTET STRING
    MAX-ACCESS  read-only
    STATUS      current
    DESCRIPTION
        "MAC of wlan0."
    ::= { amWifiWlan0 1 }

Wlan0IPAddress OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX      OCTET STRING
    MAX-ACCESS  read-only
    STATUS      current
    DESCRIPTION
        "IP of wlan0."
    ::= { amWifiWlan0 2 } 

Wlan0LinkStatus OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX      OCTET STRING
    MAX-ACCESS  read-only
    STATUS      current
    DESCRIPTION
        "The link status of WLAN0 interface."
    ::= { amWifiWlan0 3 } 

Wlan1MacAddress OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX      OCTET STRING
    MAX-ACCESS  read-only
    STATUS      current
    DESCRIPTION
        "MAC of wlan1."
    ::= { amWifiWlan1 1 }

Wlan1IPAddress OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX      OCTET STRING
    MAX-ACCESS  read-only
    STATUS      current
    DESCRIPTION
        "IP of wlan1."
    ::= { amWifiWlan1 2 } 

Wlan1LinkStatus OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX      OCTET STRING
    MAX-ACCESS  read-only
    STATUS      current
    DESCRIPTION
        "The link status of WLAN1 interface."
    ::= { amWifiWlan1 3 } 

Wlan2MacAddress OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX      OCTET STRING
    MAX-ACCESS  read-only
    STATUS      current
    DESCRIPTION
        "MAC of wlan2."
    ::= { amWifiWlan2 1 }

Wlan2IPAddress OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX      OCTET STRING
    MAX-ACCESS  read-only
    STATUS      current
    DESCRIPTION
        "IP of wlan2."
    ::= { amWifiWlan2 2 } 

Wlan2LinkStatus OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX      OCTET STRING
    MAX-ACCESS  read-only
    STATUS      current
    DESCRIPTION
        "The link status of WLAN2 interface."
    ::= { amWifiWlan2 3 } 

Wlan3MacAddress OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX      OCTET STRING
    MAX-ACCESS  read-only
    STATUS      current
    DESCRIPTION
        "MAC of wlan3."
    ::= { amWifiWlan3 1 }

Wlan3IPAddress OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX      OCTET STRING
    MAX-ACCESS  read-only
    STATUS      current
    DESCRIPTION
        "IP of wlan3."
    ::= { amWifiWlan3 2 } 

Wlan3LinkStatus OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX      OCTET STRING
    MAX-ACCESS  read-only
    STATUS      current
    DESCRIPTION
        "The link status of WLAN3 interface."
    ::= { amWifiWlan3 3 } 

LanMacAddress OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX      OCTET STRING
    MAX-ACCESS  read-only
    STATUS      current
    DESCRIPTION
        "MAC of LAN."
    ::= { amMibLan 1 }

LanIPAddress OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX      OCTET STRING
    MAX-ACCESS  read-only
    STATUS      current
    DESCRIPTION
        "IP of LAN."
    ::= { amMibLan 2 } 

LanLinkStatus OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX      OCTET STRING
    MAX-ACCESS  read-only
    STATUS      current
    DESCRIPTION
        "The link status of LAN interface."
    ::= { amMibLan 3 } 

FWLocalVersion OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX      OCTET STRING
    MAX-ACCESS  read-only
    STATUS      current
    DESCRIPTION
        "Local Software  Version."
    ::= { amMibVersion 1 }

FWOTAServerVersion OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX      OCTET STRING
    MAX-ACCESS  read-only
    STATUS      current
    DESCRIPTION
        "OTA Server Version."
    ::= { amMibVersion 2 } 

LoginUserNum OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX      OCTET STRING
    MAX-ACCESS  read-only
    STATUS      current
    DESCRIPTION
        "Current Login user num."
    ::= { amMibCurstatus 1 } 

InternetStatus OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX      OCTET STRING
    MAX-ACCESS  read-only
    STATUS      current
    DESCRIPTION
        "Current Internet status."
    ::= { amMibCurstatus 2 }

END
```

Comment: What have you tried? Everything seems to be there for SNMPv3 queries.

Comment: I have tried SNMPv3 but I want to have that file as OIDs to use it in a NodeJS Application.

Comment: Use snmpwalk to traverse the MIB with the access parameters in your original post. That will give you the OIDs. There are many other ways to get the OIDs but they are more complicated.

Comment: How do I do that? Could you please post the command?

Comment: Google snmpwalk

Comment: What data do you want? You didn't say.

Comment: I want to query everything.

Comment: When I use the following command: snmpwalk -a MD5 -A 12345678 -u snmpadmin -x DES -X ezcastdes -v3 192.168.62.219 47659

I get No log handling enabled - using stderr logging
snmp_build: unknown failuresnmpwalk: Error building ASN.1 representation (Can't build OID for variable)

I am running this on macOS